# C++ string cout character lost

Tags: c++, std, iostream

This is a console application in Visual studio and so I wanted to see what happened if I called a `cout` in a `cout`. And it works kinda but it removes a character which is kinda weird. So it removes the amount of characters from the `string` in the `cout` in the `main`. So it removes as much characters to the value of the return of the `doPrint()` function.

Example:
if the return value is 1 it will output "AAAAABLLLLLLLLLL"
if the return value is 2 it will output "AAAAALLLLLLLLLL"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int doPrint()
{
    std::cout << "AAAAA" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "BBLLLLLLLLLL" + doPrint() << std::endl;
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

It isn't that big of a deal but I would like to know why this happens.
Thanks already.

P.S: I know I should do `<<` instead of `+`

Comment: `"BBLLLLLLLLLL" + doPrint()` certainly doesn't do what you may be think it does. Read about pointer aritmethics.

Comment: This can be simplified to `int main() { std::cout << "ABC\n" + 1; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically what happens is pointer arithmetic and specified evaluation order of function calls.

```
"BBLLLLLLLLLL" + doPrint()
```

So

```
"BBLLLLLLLLLL" + 1
```

yields

```
BLLLLLLLLLL
```

and

```
"BBLLLLLLLLLL" + 2
```

yields

```
LLLLLLLLLL
```

with `std::cout`.

It applies function pointer arithmetic with the character array literal, and *"looses"* characters, as `doPrint()` yields something bigger than `0`.

The operator precedence of `+` is higher than `<<`, hence `doPrint()` is called first and prints `AAAAA`. So your staement

```
 std::cout << "BBLLLLLLLLLL" + doPrint() << std::endl;
```

breaks down to

1. call `doPrint()`
   1.1. call `std::cout << "AAAAA" << std::endl;`
2. call `"BBLLLLLLLLLL" + 1` from the result value of `doPrint()`
3. call `std::ostream& operator<<(std::otream&, const char*)`
4. call `std::endl`

Comment: @user4568696 Well, to really get it bumped as a _nice answer_ it'll need another 10 upvotes at this time :-P ...

Comment: @Boopy Don't worry I'm just joking regarding the [_nice answer badge_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=1413395), I've got enough rewards already ;-). Finding the accept button was at least good enough action from your side.